# Norm of transpose is equal to norm of operator

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, dual-spaces

$X,Y$ are normed spaces. For a linear map $T:X\rightarrow Y$ define $T^{*}:Y^*\rightarrow X^*$ by $T^*(f)=f\circ T$.

If $T$ is bounded I have to show that $\|{T}\|=\|{T^*}\|$. Showing $\|T^*\|\leq\|T\|$ was easy. For the converse I tried this :

We have $\|T^{**}\|\leq\|T^*\|$. If I can show $\|T\|\leq\|T^{**}\|$ then I am done. Now $\|T^{**}(f)\|=\|f\circ T^*\|$. Then $\|T^{**}(J_x)\|=\|J_x\circ T^*\|$ where $J$ is the natural inclusion of $X$ into $X^{**}$. $$|J_x\circ T^*(f)|=|J_x(T^*(f))|=|J_x(f\circ T)|=|f\circ T(x)|$$
Now for each $x\in X$ $\exists$ a continuous linear functional $f$ on $Y$ such that $\|f\|=1$ and $f(Tx)=\|Tx\|$ (Hahn-Banach Theorem). For such an $f$ the last expression becomes $\|Tx\|$. So that $$\|J_x\circ T^*\|\geq\|Tx\|$$
which means $$\|T^{**}\|=\sup\limits_{\|g\|=1}\|T^{**}(g)\|\geq\sup\limits_{\|x\|=1}\|T^{**}(J_x)\|\geq\sup\limits_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|=\|T\|$$
since $\|J_x\|=\|x\|$.

Is there something wrong? Is there a simpler proof? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I didn't read your proof in full detail, but it seems correct. However you get a bit lost in not so relevant side details. You can summarise what you are doing with two sentences: 1. $T^{**}(J(x))[f] = J(x) [T^*(f)] = T^*(f)\,[x]= f[T(x)] = J(T(x))[f]$ and hence $T^{**}\circ J = J\circ T$. 2. Since $J$ is isometric you get that $\|T^{**}\|≥\|T\|$.

Comment: @s.harp $T:X\rightarrow Y$ and $J:X\rightarrow X^{**}$; how are you defining $J\circ T$?

Comment: That was a bit sloppy, there are two $J$ maps, once from $X\to X^{**}$ and once from $Y\to Y^{**}$. The equation should be $T^{**} \circ J_X = J_Y\circ T$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an argument without involving the double dual.

Given $x\in X$, one of the most common application of the Hahn-Banach Theorem implies there exists $g\in Y^*$ such that $\|g\|=1$ and
$$
\|Tx\|=g(Tx).
$$
So
$$
\|Tx\|=g(Tx)=(T^*g)x\leq\|T^*g\|\,\|x\|\leq \|T^*\|\,\|x\|.
$$
Thus $\|T\|\leq\|T^*\|$.